# executing javascript functions within a string

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a better way to inject a dynamic text into the html string other than the code specified below?

var code = 'siteCode1';

html code as a string:

```
existing: '<p>Log in with your'+ eval("siteVarObj('+code+').siteName") +'account</p>',


function siteVarObj(siteCode){
            if(siteCode === 'siteCode1'){
                this.siteName = 'google.com';
                this.siteContactUsURL = '';
            }else if(siteCode === 'siteCode2'){
                this.siteName = 'stackoverflow.com';
                this.siteContactUsURL = '';
            }
            return this;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
var code = 'siteCode1';
var myHTMLString = '<p>Log in with your '+ siteVarObj(code).siteName + ' account</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generally suggest to avoid execution of any input from within eval because
eval opens up your code for injection attacks when used inproperly.